# Sublime SFTP plugin

Tags: sftp, sublime-text-2, sublime-text-3

I am facing a problem with SFTP plugin for sublime. It works and upload files and folders properly, but when a file is located in subdirectory of directory it does not actualy upload the file. It shows that the file has been uploaded but it does not show on webpage. The only way how to get it working is to refresh the main parent folder.

my case: pages/dogs/menu.php

i have to upload whole pages folder to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to this was that it was being uploaded to Pages folder instead of pages.

So make sure to be careful with casing.